# Why jquery ui button looks different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, jquery-ui, firefox, google-chrome

I have uploaded an example page
https://bobdn.com/Temp.aspx.

This page has just a single jquery UI button.

Why does this look little large in firefox.
Padding and font-size both look large.
It looks fine in chrome.

How can I make it equal size (padding, font etc) for both browser.??

Comment: looks exactly the same to me. tested browser versions?

Comment: @codef0rmer FF 11.0 and Chrome 19.0.1055.1

Comment: @EliranMalka FF 11.0 and Chrome 19.0.1055.1

Comment: Check whether the page has zoom level set in FF. Try pressing CTRL+0 (zero)

Comment: @codef0rmer I have already tried this. Zoom level is normal in both browser. I have also removed reference of my own developed css (updated page on server). But it still look little larger in FF.

Answer (score 2):

My guess it that it's inconsistent rendering of the `<input>` element. I can verify that the rendering is inconsistent between each browser, with a 2px height difference.

If you can use a `<button>` element instead, you may find that it renders more consistently from browser to browser, although you will most likely have to adjust padding yourself.

That done, you need to try setting any of the relevant styles explicitly, rather than relying on defaults.
This includes: line-height, padding, font-size, border-width, and perhaps more.
Every browser has it's own defaults.
If you want consistency, you must provide css that replaces the default values.

Comment: does this look larger for u in FF..?? @Eliran said it looks exactly same for him. I have already tried adjusting padding, but not fixed. Still larger in FF.

Comment: It's 2 pixels taller in FF, and 7 pixels wider.

Comment: So what is the solution for this..?? I want buttons to look like as it looks in firefox.

Comment: I can't use `<button>` because my application is an asp.net application. `<asp:Button>` is rendered as `<input type="submit">`. What can I do in this case..??

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by setting the defaults explicitly.
Ex. I created a input.navigation_button CSS class with padding:2px   (Chrome had zero padding on my buttons).