# Different 'back' buttons generated depending on browser using jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, blackberry, jquery-mobile

The back button appears different on chrome and blackberry using jQuery mobile. Is this just how the browser implements these buttons or can I be changed so that it appears the same across all browsers, mobile or not ?

Chrome back button :

[image]

Blackberry back button :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually was for me that I was not hosting the jquery mobile images. So they were not being found.

Answer (score 0):

You can have full control on the buttons: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html
However, you could see that the assest/css for creating are similar. 
So I guess it's the implementation of webkit that is a bit different between the devices.

It's similar to this question: [Why jquery ui button looks different in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121131/why-jquery-ui-button-looks-different-in-firefox-and-chrome)